# Is it possible to merge properties from two objects in neo4j before returning?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

In javascript we can merge properties from two object like below:

```
const ob1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const ob2 = { c: 3, d: 4 };
const ob3 = { ...ob1, ...ob2 }; // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
```

Can we do the same in cypher queries while returning data? Currently I have the query like below:

```
MATCH (n1:Node1)-[r:RELATION]->(n2:Node2)
RETURN n1{ .*, rel: PROPERTIES(r) }
```

What I want is to include all the properties of `r` in the returned object instead of adding the `rel` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a [`apoc.map.merge`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) function from the apoc library:

```
MATCH (n1:Node1)-[r:RELATION]->(n2:Node2)
RETURN apoc.map.merge(n1, r)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. :)